# Was sind die Regeln der hochdeutschen Auslautverhärtung?

Tags: pronunciation

Hat Hochdeutsch eine allgemeine Regel für die Auslautverhärtung?

> Die Buchstaben  werden am Wort- und Silbenende wie [p,
>   t, k] ausgesprochen (Auslautverhärtung) (Phonetik lehren und lernen,
>   Goethe-Institut 2000, S. 197)
>
> die Auslautverhärtung: Man spricht im Wortauslaut und vor Konsonanten:
>   b als p, d als t, g als k oder Ich-Laut, v/w als f, z als s
>   (https://www.lernnetz24.de/regeln/0001.html)

z.B. Ab|do|men[ˌapˈdoːmən], aber warum gilt es nicht für ab|ra|siv [abʁaˈziːf], Seg|ler [ˈzeːɡlɐ], leug|nen ['lɔɪ̯ɡnən], eb|nen [ˈeːbnən]?

> /b, d, g, v, z/ werden als [p(ʰ), t(ʰ), k(ʰ), f, s] realisiert:
>   im Wortauslaut; im Morphemauslaut/ vor Morphemgrenze und es folgt ein
>   Morphem, das mit stimmlosen Fortiskonsonanten anlautet; im
>   Morphemauslaut/ vor Morphemgrenze, die zugleich Silbengrenze ist und
>   es folgt ein konsonantisch anlautendes Morphem
>   (http://143.50.35.73/wiki/index.php/Auslautverh%C3%A4rtung)

Diese letzte Regel sagt mir sehr zu, aber die Abhandlung bezieht sich auf 
die Sprache des Mittelalters und warum denn dann [ˌapˈdoːmən]?

Comment: Ich verstehe Deine Beispiele nicht ganz. Weder bei Segler, noch bei Leugnen oder ebnen kommt der Fall vor.

Comment: Die Silbifizierungen *Seg|ler*, *leug|nen*, *eb|nen* sind falsch. Im Duden dient der senkrechte Strich | zur Angabe von Wortrennungen, nicht Silbengrenzen. Die Silbengrenzen sind *Se.gler*, *leu.gnen*, *e.bnen*.

Comment: Ich spreche *Abdomen* ohne Verhärtung aus.

Comment: @PMF: Das sind wohl die Ausnahmen, genauso wie *abrasiv*.

Comment: @David: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Segler --> "Worttrennung: *Seg|ler*". Das trennt m.E. die *Sil|ben*.

Comment: Worttrennung berücksichtigt manchmal die Silben, manchmal nicht: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/worttrennung. Beispiel: Na|ti|on, gesprochen zweisilbig.

Comment: Naaa-tiii-on. Warum nicht dreisilbig?

Comment: Es gibt viele Wörter auf *-tion*, bei denen die Aussprache [tsjo:n] ist: *Aktion, Lektion, Kaution, Sanktion, ...* Im Duden steht dann als Worttrennung immer *|ti|on*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Regel geht aber noch weiter:

> Ausnahme: Folgen auf [b d g] im Wortstamm [l], [ʁ] oder [n] und folgt
>   auf diese Lautverbindung ein Sufﬁx, tritt keine Auslautverhärtung
>   ein.

(Quelle: Rues et al. Phonetische Transkription des Deutschen, Tübingen 2009, Seite 36)

also:

> Merke: [b d g] und [v z ʒ] werden in der Silbenkoda als [p t k] und [f s ʃ] 
>   realisiert – außer es folgen [l, ʁ, n] im Wortstamm vor einem Sufﬁx.

Comment: soweit die "offiziellen" Regeln, ob dann tagtäglich wirklich so gesprochen wird, ist eine andere Sache (ich z.B. sage auch [ˌabˈdoːmən])

Answer (score 1):

Ich hab die Diskussion in den Kommentaren mitverfolgt, und es zeigt sich eines deutlich: Ausgesprochene Sprache unterscheidet sich teilweise sogar von Dorf zu Dorf, solche Regeln sind daher nur bedingt anwendbar. Ich persönlich komme aus dem Schwäbischen, hier gibt es gar keine harten Laute.

Nun aber zu der Frage:
Zum einen hat David Vogt ganz richtig angemerkt, dass die Silbentrennung bei einigen Wörtern falsch ist. Ein weiterer Punkt ist der Sprachfluss. Auch wenn die Regel der phonetischen Lautverhärtung generell korrekt ist, fühlt sich das Sprechen solcher Worte "holprig" an. Speziell wenn der Silbenübergang generell weicher Natur ist, liegen harte Laute falsch auf der Zunge. Bei Wörtern wie Abdomen lassen sich die Laute 'b' und 'd' nicht binden. Folgen Laute wie 'l' oder 'n' entsteht diese phonetische Lücke nicht, folglich kann der Laut weich gesprochen werden.